# Can not send mail via SMTP yandex error 553

Tags: java, android, smtp, sendmail

Setting up sending mail via smtp.

```
private String mailhost = "smtp.yandex.ru";
private String user;
private String password;
private Session session;

public static final String TAG = "GMailSender: ";

static {
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
}

public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
}

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
}
```

I do it according to this instruction https://yandex.ru/support/mail/mail-clients/others.html. a password from passwords for applications. But I get the error Error sending mail com. sun. mail. smtp. SMTPSendFailedException:553 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: does not belong to the auth user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rephrasing the error message:

> The `user` you log in with is not authorized to send email on behalf of the email address listed in the `from` field of the email (the sender).

This kind of security is used to prevent you from sending spam email, pretending to be someone else.

Comment: I do not specify the sender, I only log in. If the sender specifies the same email as for logging in, will it work? How do I do this?

Comment: @Ксения How do you do what? Specify the `from` field of an email to be sent? Depends on how you create the email (what API you use).

Comment: yes, it works. must add   message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mymail@yandex.ru"));

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an error on yandex side. I cannot send email as well via SMTP.